# Why can't I draw onto two different bitmaps in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to draw a button on a bitmap object. Depending on the y position, it should draw on bitmap1 if the y position is within bmp1's height value, and bitmap2 if it isn't.
For some reason this does not work:

```
wx.Button(bitmap1 if ypos <= bmp1.GetHeight() else bitmap2, label='Run', id=i, pos=(xpos, ypos))
```

I can only draw the button on *one* wx.StaticBitmap image or the panel. The images parents are the panel.

This works fine if I want to switch between the bitmap *or* onto the panel directly.

What gives?

**NOTE:**
I managed to work around this using PIL to create a dynamic image large enough to accomodate my generated buttons (a continuous y-size, according to their count and placement), however this idea/code should still be valid.

If I substitute the 'bitmap2' value for the panel, and shift the bitmap2 image drawn on the panel by a bit, then I see that the program draws underneath bitmap2. Why? The image is placed exactly like bitmap1, and bitmap1 has no problems being drawn on it by buttons? :O

Comment: Frankly I'm stunned that you `can` incorporate an `if` statement inside a button definition, which led to much confusion on my part but you can't just make any widget the `child` of any other widget. The `parent` widget must be capable of handling `child` widgets e.g. `wx.Frame` and `wx.Panel`. I'm prepared to be corrected on this, as you already managed to perform what I thought to be impossible. ;)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony is that a good enough reason to downvote?
Anyway - you can do ifs here, as you see. However my problem is that the drawing can seemingly only be done on one picture and the panel, but not on one picture or another picture.
I am doing just that - assigning which parent to draw on, but it seems to not want to draw onto two images if one is completed. I am generating n buttons.
Any help?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I added a note with some more context if it helps in the thought process

Comment: The person who comments is not necessarily the down-voter. It was not my down vote. I was too amazed by the `if` statement to consider voting at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

The button's parent object should get the ypos according to the parent's dimensions, not on where it is drawn on the frame, like so:

```
wx.Button(bitmap1 if ypos <= bmp1.GetHeight() else bitmap2, label='Run {i}', id=i, pos=(80, ypos if ypos <= bmp1.GetHeight() else ypos-img_height))
```

**ypos if ypos <= bmp1.GetHeight() else ypos-img_height**

Finally!

Comment: Well done! However, consider creating variables for the bitmap, position etc as this method may well prove to be less than maintainable. It is a very strange way to do things but if you are comfortable with it, fine. Python proves that there are many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I think it was a noob mistake on my part, but I presumed falsly that the drawing was in absolute frame coordinates for both images. I was wrong, because the buttons have their parent, but this was being handled in a loop and I was a bit lost. The coordinate scheme I have going on is easy enough to maintain with 7-10 variables. Most of the elements in my UI are generated according to a scanned path, so it makes sense to have a loop and make that dynamic.